Netgate 1100 will not even install USB factory firmware/image
After I could not connect to my Netgate 1100 router, I did unplug the power to reboot it, but since then it cannot boot at all.
This is what is being shown in console:
OK TIM-1.0
WTMI-devel-18.12.1-1a13f2f
WTMI: system early-init
SVC REV: 5, CPU VDD voltage: 1.237V
NOTICE:  Booting Trusted Firmware
NOTICE:  BL1: v1.5(release):1f8ca7e-dirty (Marvell-devel-18.12.2)
NOTICE:  BL1: Built : 18:22:47, Oct  7 2021
NOTICE:  BL1: Booting BL2
NOTICE:  BL2: v1.5(release):1f8ca7e-dirty (Marvell-devel-18.12.2)
NOTICE:  BL2: Built : 18:22:52, Oct  7 2021
NOTICE:  BL1: Booting BL31
NOTICE:  BL31: v1.5(release):1f8ca7e-dirty (Marvell-devel-18.12.2)
NOTICE:  BL31: Built : 18

U-Boot 2018.03-devel-18.12.3-gc9aa92c-dirty (Oct 07 2021 - 18:20:55 -0300)

Model: Netgate 1100
       CPU     1200 [MHz]
       L2      800 [MHz]
       TClock  200 [MHz]
       DDR     750 [MHz]
DRAM:  1 GiB
Comphy chip #0:
Comphy-0: USB3          5 Gbps    
Comphy-1: PEX0          2.5 Gbps  
Comphy-2: SATA0         6 Gbps    
SATA link 0 timeout.
AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
flags: ncq led only pmp fbss pio slum part sxs 
PCIE-0: Link down
MMC:   sdhci@d0000: 0, sdhci@d8000: 1
Loading Environment from SPI Flash... SF: Detected mx25u3235f with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 4 MiB
OK
Model: Netgate 1100
Net:   eth0: neta@30000 [PRIME]
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 

U-Boot 2018.03-devel-18.12.3-gc9aa92c-dirty (Oct 07 2021 - 18:20:55 -0300)

Model: Netgate 1100
       CPU     1200 [MHz]
       L2      800 [MHz]
       TClock  200 [MHz]
       DDR     750 [MHz]
DRAM:  1 GiB
Comphy chip #0:
Comphy-0: USB3          5 Gbps    
Comphy-1: PEX0          2.5 Gbps  
Comphy-2: SATA0         6 Gbps    
SATA link 0 timeout.
AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
flags: ncq led only pmp fbss pio slum part sxs 
PCIE-0: Link down
MMC:   sdhci@d0000: 0, sdhci@d8000: 1
Loading Environment from SPI Flash... SF: Detected mx25u3235f with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 4 MiB
OK
Model: Netgate 1100
Net:   eth0: neta@30000 [PRIME]
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
Card did not respond to voltage select!
    18022   armada-3720-netgate-1100.dtb
    18022   armada-3720-sg1100.dtb
    12944   armada-3720-netgate-2100.dtb
    12944   armada-3720-sg2100.dtb

4 file(s), 0 dir(s)

845140 bytes read in 37 ms (21.8 MiB/s)
18022 bytes read in 13 ms (1.3 MiB/s)
## Starting EFI application at 07000000 ...
Card did not respond to voltage select!
Scanning disk sdhci@d0000.blk...
Disk sdhci@d0000.blk not ready
Scanning disk sdhci@d8000.blk...
Found 4 disks

Consoles: EFI console  m SPI Flash... SF: Detected mx25u3235f with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 4 MiB
    Reading loader env vars from /efi/freebsd/loader.env
Setting currdev to disk0p2:
FreeBSD/arm64 EFI loader, Revision 1.1
(Fri Apr 19 00:28:52 UTC 2024 root@freebsd)
Marvell>> <INTERRUPT>
   Command line arguments: loader.efi
   Image base: 0x70000002f
   EFI version: 2.70nit
   EFI Firmware: Das U-Boot (rev 0.00)
   Console: efi,comconsole (0)are
   Load Path: /\armada-3720-sg1100.dtbrty (Marvell-devel-18.12.2)
   Load Device: /VenHw(e61d73b9-a384-4acc-aeab-82e828f3628b)/eMMC(1)/eMMC(0)/HD(2,GPT,0bf72bee-1c45-11ef-a845-9b51e061f96f,0x84000,0x20000)
Trying ESP: /VenHw(e61d73b9-a384-4acc-aeab-82e828f3628b)/eMMC(1)/eMMC(0)/HD(2,GPT,0bf72bee-1c45-11ef-a845-9b51e061f96f,0x84000,0x20000)
Setting currdev to disk0p2::1f8ca7e-dirty (Marvell-devel-18.12.2)
Trying: /VenHw(e61d73b9-a384-4acc-aeab-82e828f3628b)/eMMC(1)/eMMC(0)/HD(1,GPT,0bf72bee-1c45-11ef-a845-9b51e061f96f,0x28,0x82000)
Setting currdev to disk0p1:
Trying: /VenHw(e61d73b9-a384-4acc-aeab-82e828f3628b)/eMMC(1)/eMMC(0)/HD(3,GPT,0bf72bee-1c45-11ef-a845-9b51e061f96f,0xa4000,0xdea000)
Setting currdev to zfs:pfSense/ROOT/default:
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5vel-18.12.3-gc9aa92c-dirty (Oct 07 2021 - 18:20:55 -0300)
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 500
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 50 [MHz]
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5       2.5 Gbps  
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5ut.
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailablepl SATA mode
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5nt from SPI Flash... SF: Detected mx25u3235f with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 4 MiB
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5@30000 [PRIME]
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5ond to voltage select!
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5a-3720-netgate-2100.dtb
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5 in 37 ms (21.8 MiB/s)
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5pplication at 07000000 ...
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read i@d0000.blk not ready
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=11874600 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=2813232 size=32 status=7
zio_read error: 5
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
ERROR: cannot open /boot/lua/loader.lua: no such file or directory.
Type '?' for a list of commands, 'help' for more detailed help.
OK

OK, so some kind of corruption in the filesystem I expect. Then I wanted to just reinstall the factory image and setup everything again (from configuration backup), but even that I cannot do.
I do have downloaded the netgate-installer-aarch64.img.gz image from Netgate and flashed it to a USB, but the Netgate 1100 will not at all reboot it, and it just end up in the above place.
However, I can then interrupt the boot process and write these commands:
> usb start

> usb reset

> fatload usb 0:1 0x8000000 EFI/boot/BOOTaa64.efi

> bootefi 0x8000000

Doing that will show these two console screens:
FreeBSD EFI boot block
   Loader path: /boot/loader.efi

   Initializing modules: ZFS UFS
   Load Path: /MemoryMapped(0x1,0x8000000,0x802bc48)
   Probing 8 block devices...not supported
not supported
not supported
good
not supported
not supported
not supported
good
 done
    ZFS found the following pools: pfSense
    UFS found 1 partition
zio_read error: -1
zio_read error: -1
ZFS: i/o error - all block copies unavailable
Failed to lookup '/boot/loader.efi' on pool 'pfSense' (-1)

.. and then the second screen:
Consoles: EFI console  
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=64 size=1 status=7
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=64 size=1 status=7
efipart_readwrite: rw=1, blk=64 size=1 status=7
    Reading loader env vars from /efi/freebsd/loader.env
Setting currdev to disk1p3:
FreeBSD/arm64 EFI loader, Revision 1.1
(Thu Sep 19 15:08:05 UTC 2024 root@freebsd)

   Command line arguments: loader.efi -S115200 -D
   Image base: 0x3b5f47e0
   EFI version: 2.70
   EFI Firmware: Das U-Boot (rev 0.00)
   Console: efi,comconsole (0x20000000)
   Load Device: /VenHw(e61d73b9-a384-4acc-aeab-82e828f3628b)/USBClass(0,0,9,0,3)/USBClass(58f,6387,0,0,0)/HD(3,MBR,0xaefff202,0x84001,0x1fb110)
Trying ESP: /VenHw(e61d73b9-a384-4acc-aeab-82e828f3628b)/USBClass(0,0,9,0,3)/USBClass(58f,6387,0,0,0)/HD(3,MBR,0xaefff202,0x84001,0x1fb110)
Setting currdev to disk1p3:
|

This will lead to a menu, where I can select a few boot options:
   _ __  / _|___  ___ _ __  ___  ___      _                
  | '_ \| |_/ __|/ _ \ '_ \/ __|/ _ \   _| |_              
  | |_) |  _\__ \  __/ | | \__ \  __/  |_   _|             
  | .__/|_| |___/\___|_| |_|___/\___|    |_|               
  |_|                                                      
                                                           
                                                                             
+---- Welcome to Netgate pfSense Plus ----+      __________________________  
|                                         |     /                       ___\ 
|  1. Boot Multi user [Enter]             |    |                      /`     
|  2. Boot Single user                    |    |                     /    :-|
|  3. Escape to loader prompt             |    |      _________  ___/    /_ |
|  4. Reboot                              |    |    /` ____   / /__    ___/ |
|  5. Cons: Dual (Video primary)          |    |   /  /   /  /    /   /     |
|                                         |    |  /  /___/  /    /   /      |
|  Options:                               |    | /   ______/    /   /  _    |
|  6. Kernel: default/kernel (1 of 1)     |    |/   /          /   / _| |_  |
|  7. Boot Options                        |        /          /___/ |_   _| |
|                                         |       /                   |_|   |
|                                         |      /_________________________/ 
+-----------------------------------------+                                  /

Option 1 + 2 will get me stuck here:
Loading kernel...
/boot/kernel/kernel text=0x318 text=0xcbd8a8 text=0x14685c8 data=0x19cff0 data=0x0+0x2ca000 0x8+0x19d058+0x8+0x1b8d23
Loading configured modules...
can't find '/etc/hostid'
can't find '/boot/entropy'
No valid device tree blob found!
WARNING! Trying to fire up the kernel, but no device tree blob found!

With option 3 I do have some commands available, but even if some hours with ChatGPT, I have not been able to get any result.
I find it weird that even if the eMMC is broken/faulty, that it then will not even boot the USB, but would anyone have any idea what I could try to get this working again?
I am not a little reluctant buying a new Netgate, if it breaks so easy when being unplugged from its power.
